# How to only show ng-repeat items that are for certain date?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/i3QqSOxTtJpXBo0qsQds?p=preview)

I have some json that is being brought into a view via ng-repeat.  I have a datepicker directive that sets a date variable in the model (I called the date `todaysDate`).

[image]

How do I show only the items that fit the date the user specifies?  So let's say I have a bunch of json that looks like this, but has a variety of items with different dates.

```
 "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-122.4352424165, 37.23259223224644]
        },
        "properties": {
            "id": "0",
            "date": "2014-07-12",
            "time": "22:00:00",
            "artist": "heheheh",
            "venue": "Place",
            "price": "$20"
        }
```

Let's say there's 500 items/events with different dates.  I'll use the current date (aka 'today') as the default mode for items/events to show.  I want the user to be able to specify which ones they want to see (should they want to see items happening in the future).

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/i3QqSOxTtJpXBo0qsQds?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, please provide a plunkr so we can have something to work with here, what needs to be defined is a custom filter that accepts argument

Comment: ok my bad.  Will plunkr

Comment: @Linial [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/i3QqSOxTtJpXBo0qsQds?p=preview) Could not get the dang datepicker directive to work but I'm wondering if this plunker will give you enough of an idea of what I'm working with.  You'll see `$scope.todaysDate` in the script.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a filter to your `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in aBunchOfItems | filter: {properties: {date: '2014-07-12'}}">
```

Comment: Thanks.  How to filter off of a dynamic variable set by the datepicker directive?

Comment: Same, just substitute you variable instead of `2014-07-12`. Just remember, this is a string comparison. If you need something more complex, you can create a custom filter.

Comment: I think this answered what I asked but I basically took your tip of using a custom filter and went that route instead.